# Entity Framework and entities states

Tags: entity-framework

If you load an entity from Entity Framework and you store the reference somewhere. Does entity framework keep trace of the object until it get disposed ? can you save the state of the object anytime ? (How does it keep trace of it) We are talking about an application not a web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For as long as your database context exists, the entity will be tracked. This is assuming you don't manually detach it.

Consider (freehand/pseudo):

```
MyEntity entity;

using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    entity = context.MyEntities.First();
}

entity.Property1 = "something"; // success
entity.LazyNavigationProperty.Property2 = "something"; // fail
```

The lazy loading will fail because you've disposed the context and the connection with it.

Whereas consider:

```
var context = new MyDbContext())
MyEntity entity = context.MyEntities.First();

entity.Property1 = "something"; // success

// do loads of stuff

entity.LazyNavigationProperty.Property2 = "something"; // success

context.SaveChanges();
```

The context is still open so the entity will be tracked and persisted on demand.

Answer (score 1):

If you load an entity it will be tracked in ObjectStateManager until the ObjectContext is disposed. You can load is as no tracking though - with DbContext (or to be more correct DbSet) you can use [`.AsNoTracking`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in your query

Answer (score 1):

dont forget if you use .AsNoTracking you entity is out of the context and will just a object and you cant persist or make changes.